# Pixel-perfect jitter-free motion

Tags: 2d, movement, pixel-art

Here's a thing I cannot wrap my head around:

When we are talking about low-resolution pixel art, there is a subcategory that deals with pixel perfection: Like in the olden days you are restricted to a grid and each pixel can only take up a complete square on that grid. No half-pixel shifts, no rotated pixels, no mixed resolution, no bilinear interpolation.

Now let's talk about animation for pixel perfect games: I can easily get smooth animation if I move a sprite by integer speeds: 1 pixel per frame, 2 pixels per frame, etc. For slower speeds I can stretch my movement over multiple frames: 1 pixel per 2 frames, 1 pixel per 3 frames, etc.

This however is very impractical since the few available speeds are very limiting. So the solution to my understanding is to use float speeds, which of course result in float positions, which are rounded before drawing the sprite to the pixel grid. This allows for basically any movement speed and can also deal with the problem of inconsistent frame rates by using variable movement that is adjusted by the current frame rate.

Here's the problem though: If I am living in the world of low-resolution perfect pixel art, this rounding to full pixels can and will introduce ugly jitter effects. The lower the resolution, the more apparent it becomes.

Consider this:

My sprite speed is 1.01 pixels per frame. Since we are dealing with rounded positions, my sprite will move at a steady and smooth 1 pixels per frame for the first 50 frames because we are rounding down (0.0, 1.01, 2.02, ..., 49.49). As soon as the sprite reaches frame 51, we start rounding up (50.50 becomes 51), so for that single frame the sprite will move 2 pixels (from 49 to 51), which can be perceived as a movement hiccup. Afterwards it will run smoothly for another 100 frames until the next change from rounding down to rounding up occurs and we have another hiccup. This becomes even worse if we have variable speeds (e.g. for acceleration and deceleration). And it seems that this is a fundamental rule independent from the engine used.

What I cannot get my head around is how the games from the olden days ran so smoothly? I don't recall Super Mario Bros or Super Metroid having any of those jitter effects, they were running absolutely smoothly, so what gives? At least for SMB, I know that they had some clever way of storing the fractional parts of the sprite positions, so they must have used some variant of the float-and-round-technique.

I only recently started thinking about this topic, because I have a hard time understanding why Game Maker Studio is able to pull off butter-smooth movement and pixel-precision at the same time, while Godot seems to be struggling with this. Anybody with in-depth knowledge of the two engines who can tell me what magic trick I may be missing?

There must be a solution to this because there are many pixel-art games, modern and classic alike, that are running absolutely smoothly and obey the rules of the perfectly aligned pixel at the same time.

I read the answers over at [How do you move a sprite in sub-pixel increments?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87353/how-do-you-move-a-sprite-in-sub-pixel-increments) but didn't find them very convincing, because they would be either too resource-hungry for games of the NES era or do not apply to scrolling backgrounds.

So I would like to ask the question with the specific focus on the context of what a solution would look like in the world of old-timey consoles that did not have the resources to go for interpolation, super-resolution or other fancy stuff we have access to nowadays.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a full reference, but SMB definitely had subpixel position values, another integer besides the x and y position. It probably jitters less because the movement is less than one pixel per frame.

Comment: @jay Thank you, I know. This is what I meant with "fractional parts of sprite positions". But even SMB is limited to the pixel grid, and the fractional parts have to be rounded to int every time a sprite is drawn and then the effect I described should occur. There is subpixel accuracy internally, but there cannot be subpixel precision when drawing the sprite because we have a fixed pixel grid.

Comment: I've recently starting diving deeper into gamedev so I may be completely off track here, but sounds like what Unity refers to as 2D camera size? https://blog.unity.com/technology/pixel-perfect-2d AFAIU, this allows movement to take place perfectly on the grid, avoiding having to deal with sub-pixel calculations. Again, maybe completely off track, but this whole PPU and camera size tunings blew my (very novice) mind.

Comment: The Nintendo games are not entirely jitter-free.  I’ve been studying some GameBoy games while working on this kind of problem and they do jitter.  I think it’s less noticeable on a small screen.